# IIS Reverse proxy get 404 from NodeJS behind it

Tags: node.js, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, rocket.chat

I know there are many articles about reverse proxy, there are many thing about `InBound` and `OutBound` but I would like to know what wrong I have done.

I have NodeJs server which is available on `http://192.168.0.1:3000`
When I create reverse proxy by Server Farms like below

**Pattern** : `*`
**Action Type:** `Route To Server Farm`
**Scheme:** `http` , **Server Farm:** `FarmName`, **Path:**  `{R:0}`
when I browse `http://localhost` everything works like a charm , but problem is based on sub domain or sub folder request.

I want proxy `http://localhost/site/sub1` to `http://192.168.0.1:3000` I established `InBound` and `OutBound` rules like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <globalRules>
    <rule name="ARR_testd_loadbalance" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^site/sub1(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.1:3000/{R:1}" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
    <rule name="query" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^sockjs/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.1:3000/sockjs/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </globalRules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="RewriteAbsoluteUrlsInResponse" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
      <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.0.1(\:3000)?/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/site/sub1/{R:3}" />
    </rule> 
    <rule name="RewriteRelativePaths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
      <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/site/sub1/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Restore-AcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
      <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)"></match>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}"></action>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
      </preCondition>
      <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

based on above rules I still see the error from NodeJs server as:
When page get loaded from NodeJS it shows me the `404` error like:

> Error:404
>   Oops, page not found
>   Sorry, page you requested does not exists or was deleted!

and in private Rocket server I can see

> [34mI20190129-17:17:04.122(3.5) rocketchat:logger server.js:199 [34mMeteor ➔ method public-settings/get -> userId: null , arguments:  [] 
>   [34mI20190129-17:17:04.125(3.5) meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions { id: 'TFhMadFtuynon7rHB',   clientAddress: '192.168.0.201',   httpHeaders:     { **referer: 'http://localhost/site/sub1**',      'x-forwarded-for': '[::1]:3704,192.168.0.201',      'x-forwarded-host': '192.168.0.9:3000',      'x-forwarded-port': '3000',      'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',      host: '192.168.0.9:3000',      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.116',      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' },   userId: null }

and if `RewriteAbsoluteUrlsInResponse` and `RewriteRelativePaths` are working why I am getting the `404` error from NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work really,
When I enabled Reverse proxy on any address `*` wildcard everything work nice, I think there is something happened in ARR module which is violated when I want reverse works on `site/sub1`, after many tries like checking network packets by [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on private server to find failed `http` requests, defining outbounds and inbounds rules and etc, it doesn't work still.

I have to implement a workaround to do above scenario:

Making two website on different ports `80` and `81` located to:
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and `C:\inetpub\wwwroot1` the first one is main website which is browsing by
`http://localhost/site` and the second one is accessible by `http://localhost:81/reversesite` at the end defining a reverse rule in `web.config` of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot1` (reversesite) like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.1:3000/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

by browsing `http://localhost:81` it will proxied to `http://192.168.0.1:3000` and there are no any `404` error.

anyway in `http://localhost/site` I can call any api or address from `http://192.168.0.1:3000` by `http://localhost:81` but when I was trying to do reverse on `http://localhost/site/sub1` it didn't work as described in question.